# Deploy multiple platforms to Elastic Beanstalk (PHP/Python)

Tags: php, python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is it possible to deploy multiple platforms to AWS?

I have a PHP application that I would also like to run a small python script.

I see the PHP platform installs Python by default, but using `eb deploy` AWS does not pick up `requirements.txt` and install the dependencies.

I have tried installing `requirements.txt` manually which hangs when trying to install `lxml`.
I also tried adding a config file:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: application.py
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
```

But now `eb deploy` complains about:

```
ERROR: "option_settings" in one of the configuration files failed validation. More details to follow.
ERROR: Unknown or duplicate parameter: WSGIPath                     
ERROR: Unknown or duplicate parameter: NumThreads                   
ERROR: Unknown or duplicate parameter: NumProcesses
```

Which I believe is because `eb` thinks this is only a PHP app.

What is the proper way to run multiple platforms side-by-side?

Comment: I'd perhaps recommend doing this through docker containers, and linking them, and using EB docker platform. You can build an image locally, and then give that docker file to EB to build the image. Maybe this can help get you started; https://rominirani.com/docker-tutorial-series-part-8-linking-containers-69a4e5bf50fb#.l476ahig4

Comment: I would like to keep it simple since the python is very small and doesnt justify its own server. Is there a better way to run a setup script on deploy that will install the python dependencies on each server in the cluster? Im familiar with adding config files via .ebextensions, can these be used to create and run a shell script?

Comment: Going to try converting the `requirements.txt` to `.ebextentions` format, eg

`packages:
  python:
    python-beautifulsoup3: []`

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by using *.ebextentions* to run pre-install commands in the container during deployment, which required [setting the system path during `eb deploy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40311939/trouble-installing-lxml-to-elastic-beanstalk)