# Trouble installing lxml to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

Having quite a difficult time installing Python *requirements.txt* to a PHP application on Elastic Beanstalk.

Initially I had questioned the ability to [Deploy multiple platforms to Elastic Beanstalk (PHP/Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238884/deploy-multiple-platforms-to-elastic-beanstalk-php-python). While this is not possible out of the box, it is possible to run [pre-install commands via *.ebextentions*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html)

This lead to creating an *.ebextentions/install_python_requirements.config*

```
container_commands:
  python_req:
    command: 'pip install -r /var/app/ondeck/requirements.txt'
```

Trouble is, now `lxml`, a dependency in requirements, consistently fails during the deploy process. Curiously, `ssh` directly into the EC2 instance then running `pip install -r requirements.txt` completes without issue.

Why is the dependency installation succeeding via direct `ssh` access, but failing during deployment using `eb deploy` and the `install_python_requirements.config`?

Failure in */var/log/eb-activity.log*

```
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml
  gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/pip-build-A6NhcA/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
  gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Command "/usr/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-A6NhcA/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-gSsRbZ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-A6NhcA/lxml
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue ended up being the system `$PATH`. It appears that during `eb deploy` the system path is unset. The `pip install` is able to begin, as the system PATH is available to the deploy process. However, that system PATH variable is not passed into the `pip` process. Therefore, when subsequent calls to pip are attempted, they fail because they cannot find the application path. As evidenced by adding a log to the *install_python_requirements.config*

```
whome:      
  command: 'whoami'     
env:        
  command: '/bin/sh -c env'
```

Then checking */var/log/eb-activity.log* for the output of the log commands above, and noticing the absense of a `$PATH`

The solution for this was setting the PATH manually via another *.ebextentions/var.config*

```
 option_settings:
   - option_name: PATH
     value: '/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/root/bin'
```

This allowed the *requirements.txt* to complete successfully during the `eb deploy` process

Comment: hey vinnie! do you still have the same problem? I face an issue right now that lxml does not install and fails with a gcc error on stock python pip install requirements